# Tinkerpop3 jump without knowing the size of loop

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am using Gremlin-Scala and I have the following code:

```
val paths = w.as("a").out("next").jump(
  to = "a",
  jumpPredicate = { t: Traverser[Vertex] =>
    t.loops < 5
  }
).path.toList
```

I don't know when my loop will finish, so I have no access to the size and if I put wrong number for x in t.loops > x then I will have problem. I changed my code in following and it works well. it has two problems (1- it's ugly 2- I have to call get() which I think is not efficient)
Is there better way to do this?

```
val paths = w.as("a").out("next").jump(
  to = "a",
  jumpPredicate = { t: Traverser[Vertex] =>
    t.get().out("next").size > 0
  }
).path.toList
```

Answer (score 0):

Re your problems:

1: it's ugly - what exactly do you dislike about it? You could leave out the type annotation and variable names...

2: there's nothing inefficient about `.get` there - it's a simple getter on the traverser to get the element. `jump` gives you the traverser instead of the element so that you have more context - the traverser e.g. holds information about how many loops you've done so far, the path, etc.

This should work:

`val paths = w.as("a").out("next").jump(
  "a",
  _.get().out("next").size > 0
).path.toList`

Another loop example (finding the shortest path): 
http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/2014/12/27/gremlin-scala-shortest-path/